# GCC: Difference between buildroot gcc and precompiled gcc (installed with APT)?

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel, libc, buildroot

I'm trying to make custom binaries for initrd for x86 system. I took generic precompiled Debian 7 gcc (version 4.7.2-5) and compiled kernel with it. Next step was to make helloworld program instead of init script in initrd to check my development progress. Helloworld program was also compiled with that gcc. When I tried to start my custom system, kernel started with no problem, but helloworld program encountered some errors:

```
kernel: init[24879] general protection ip:7fd7271585e0 sp:7fff1ef55070 error:0 in init[7fd727142000+20000]
```

(numbers are not mine, I took similar string from google). Helloworld program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Helloworld\r\n");
    sleep(9999999);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -static -o init test.c
```

Earlier I also had stuck with same problem on ARM system (took generic compiler, compiled kernel and some binaries with it and tried to run, kernel runs, but binary - not). Solved it with complete buildroot system, and took buildroot compiler in next projects.

So my question is: what difference between gcc compiled as part of buildroot and generic precompiled gcc? 
I know that buildroot compiler is made in several steps, with differenet libs and so on, is this main difference, platform independence?

I don't need a solution, I can take buildroot anytime. I want to know source of my problem, to avoid such problems in future. Thanks.

**UPD:** Replaced sleep with while(1); and got same situation. My kernel output:

```
init[1]: general protection ip: 8053682 sp: bf978294 error: 0 in init[8048000+81000]
printk: 14300820 message suppressed.
```

and repeating every second.

**UPD2:** I added vdso32-int80.so (original name, like in kernel tree), tested - no luck.
I added ld-linux.so (2 files: ld-2.13.so with symbolic link), tested - same error.
Busybox way allows to run binaries without any of this libraries, tested by me on ARM platform.
Thanks for trying to help me, any other ideas?

Comment: Change your program, inside main() use a for(;;) loop and see what happens.

Comment: Does your initrd contain all the required shared libraries? In particular, an executable linked with -static will still need linux-vdso.so (which is actually part of the kernel) and ld-linux.so (which should be in /lib or /lib64).

Comment: BTW does the same helloworld executable work correctly when you start it from a shell instead of from init?

Comment: Arnout, pls, check an edit.